# HABTM mongoid following/follower

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, has-and-belongs-to-many

Mongoid ships with .push on a habtm, which sets a habtm relationship in both directions.  Although delete will #delete an associated record, there's no documented way to delete only a relationship that I have seen.  Is there a better way of doing this?

Is there a better way of ensuring uniqueness?

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :following, {class_name: 'User', inverse_of: :followers, inverse_class_name: 'User'}
  has_and_belongs_to_many :followers, {class_name: 'User', inverse_of: :following, inverse_class_name: 'User'}

  def follow!(user)
    self.following.push(user) # this pushes the inverse as well
    self.following_ids.uniq!
    self.save!
    user.follower_ids.uniq!
    user.save!
  end

  def unfollow!(user)
    self.following.delete(user.id)
    self.save!
    user.followers.delete(self.id)
    user.save!
  end
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Following code worked fine for me (mongoid 2.3.x):

```rb
class User
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name, type: String

  has_and_belongs_to_many :following, class_name: 'User', inverse_of: :followers, autosave: true
  has_and_belongs_to_many :followers, class_name: 'User', inverse_of: :following

  def follow!(user)
    if self.id != user.id && !self.following.include?(user)
      self.following << user
    end
  end

  def unfollow!(user)
    self.following.delete(user)
  end
end
```

No `inverse_class_name`, no save calls, no special handling, but with exclusion of self-following.

The reason is, that mongoid automatically uses `dependent: nullify` if not added to the relation statement. And with `autosave: true` the update of relationships get saved (and is only needed for following, because we do not alter followers directly). Without autosave option you need to add a save call in the methods, because mongoid doesn't automatically save relationship updates (since 2.0.0.x).

I put the if-clause as block, so you can alter it with exception handling (`else raise FooException`).

The `.delete(user)` is okay, also mentioned in the mongoid docs: http://mongoid.org/docs/relations/referenced/n-n.html (scroll down to "DEPENDENT BEHAVIOUR").

Comment: Some great stuff here.  However, I did some testing earlier, and fell in to the same trap (unless I'm mistaken): .delete(user) deletes the user from the database, and nullify refers to any references made to the now-deleted user

Comment: The .delete is on the .following hash not on the user object itself. Like doc says "Orphan a single child relation". It does the job, I tested it and it works.

Comment: The code `!self.following.include?(user)` is cool when you have not too much users inside the following relationship, but if you've got like 10K users… The performance are not very great :/

Comment: @K'ao what can be done then?  Would uniq! be any faster?  Perhaps the best way would be to handle duplicates gracefully-- although creating 10k tweets wouldn't be the fastest either..

Comment: @PeterEhrlich: We're now trying to use the most often atomic persistence ([link](http://mongoid.org/docs/persistence/atomic.html)). Take a look at #add_to_set, your condition ‘include?‘ will be no necessary with it.

Comment: Awesome dude. I needed just this feature. You saved my life.