# rails mongoid follow/unfollow guidance and optimization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, relationship, twitter-follow

i'ved been trying to find an ideal solution for following in mongoid and found this.
[HABTM mongoid following/follower](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8580822/habtm-mongoid-following-follower)

for some reason, Im not sure how optimum is this and this post was way back in 2011.

If implemented this way, followers and following ids are kept in the array. This is fine and probably quick for small amount of followers. But just imagine if there are thousands of followers, going through the array may not be the quickest way if u are search for one item in the array each time.

base on this tutorial link, http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/following-users
following is recommended to be put in the relationship table, this is quick to lookup when u need only to check on relationships.

My question to all is the code below great for mongoid optimization ? I need some expert advise how u guys are dealing with relationships when there is large amount of followers.

Thanks.

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name, type: String

  has_and_belongs_to_many :following, class_name: 'User', inverse_of: :followers, autosave: true
  has_and_belongs_to_many :followers, class_name: 'User', inverse_of: :following

  def follow!(user)
    if self.id != user.id && !self.following.include?(user)
    self.following << user
  end
 end

  def unfollow!(user)
   self.following.delete(user)
 end
 end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create an actual `Follow` model (that would therefore be persisted in its own collection) something like this:

```
class Follow
  include Mondoid::Document

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :followed_user, class_name: 'User'

end

class User
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name, type: String
  has_many :follows

  def follow!(user)
    follows.create(followed_user: user)
  end

  def unfollow!(user)
    follows.where(followed_user_id: user.id).destroy
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks a lot, i'll try this... probably this is the best way than keeping it in array. will mark in answered once i verify it.

Comment: there is another thing i need to check, for User deletion, i wonder in this code there is validation to destroy all the Follow entries for the user ? Need to verify this as well... probably not.

Comment: it works the code, but on user delete, it doesnt delete the follow entries. some kind of cleanup should be done. this is somewhat answered... thanks.

Comment: Great, glad to have helped.

Answer (score 0):

added the dependent on user destroy for completeness:

```
class Follow
  include Mondoid::Document

  belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :followed_user, class_name: 'User'

  end

class User
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name, type: String
  has_many :follows, :dependent => :destroy

  def follow!(user)
    follows.create(followed_user: user)
  end

  def unfollow!(user)
    follows.where(followed_user_id: user.id).destroy
 end
```

end