# Custom subscribe action using mongoid on Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid, database-relations

I'm trying to set up a subscribers/subscriptions (followers/following) relationship for my users with mongoDB. My question is how to access my subscribe method (in model) from the web using a button.

I've set up the model with referenced n-n relationship like this:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :username
  field :email

  has_and_belongs_to_many :subscriptions, class_name: 'User', inverse_of: :subscribers, autosave: true
  has_and_belongs_to_many :subscribers, class_name: 'User', inverse_of: :subscriptions

  def subscribe!(user)
    if self.id != user.id && !self.subscriptions.include?(user)
      self.subscriptions << user
    end
  end

  def unsubscribe!(user)
    self.subscriptions.delete(user)
  end
end
```

By using pry I have checked that subscribe! method works (which I took from this SO answer [HABTM mongoid following/follower](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8580822/habtm-mongoid-following-follower)).

Pry output showing 1 user subscribing to another

```
[8] pry(#<User>):2> self.subscribe!(User.first)
=> [#<User _id: Test, username: "Test", email: "test@test.com", subscription_ids: nil, subscriber_ids: ["brownie3003"]>]
[9] pry(#<User>):2> self
=> #<User _id: brownie3003, username: "brownie3003", email: "brownie3003@gmail.com", subscription_ids: ["Test"], subscriber_ids: nil>
```

Finally I want to add a form to users 'show.html.erb' which is just a button that calls the method in the model. Maybe I need a custom action in the users controller, I'm not really sure. This as far as I got with the form

```
<%= form_for current_user, :url => {action: 'subscribe'} do |f| %>
    <%= f.submit "Subscribe", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
```

current_user is a helper method that gets the signed in user.

I've created a subscribe method in Users Controller...

```
def subscribe
    puts "hello"
end
```

But I'm getting this error

```
No route matches {:action=>"subscribe", :id=>"beth", :controller=>"users"}
```

I'm not sure if I'm going about the right way of accessing the method in the model so hopefully someone can advise me on that and explain the best way to allow people to subscribe to each other through the web.

EDIT:

Thanks Kirti for the comment which made me realise I needed to add this line to my routes.rb

```
match '/subscribe', to: 'users#subscribe', via: 'patch'
```

Which makes it work now. Not sure on the etiquette of answers so just put it in as an edit, should I answer my own question?

Comment: Share your routes.rb file content in the question.

Comment: Thanks Kirti I figured it out based on this comment. Should I put the answer to my own question to close the question?

Comment: That's great! Of course you can answer your own question. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In answer to my own question:

I needed to include a route to this action

```
match '/subscribe', to: 'users#subscribe', via: 'patch'
```

Then whatever I had in my users_controller.rb under:

```
def subscribe
    puts "Hello"
end
```

Runs when I submit the form.